# Visual Studio 2008 won't run latest code after Build

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, splash-screen

I have a VS 2008 Windows Forms application written in VB, and have built a Splash screen that I'd like to show for 2-3 seconds before the main window is displayed.

In the **Application Events** I have added code to the *OnInitialize* event (in the namespace **My**), and set the `MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime` to 3000 milliseconds.

My issue is that even though VS builds the code without erros, what happens is the Main window is displayed with the Splash Screen (modeless, allowing clicks on the main window menu) in front of it for a few seconds.

I thought I had done everything right, so how can I force VS 2008 to run the *latest code base*?

And how can I prevent the MainWindow from showing until the Splash screen is unloaded?

Comment: Do you have any code in the Splash screen that would cause the Main window to show?  I just created a new project, added two forms, set one to startup and one to splash, and it worked as you would expect, so I am thinking there is something that is forcing the Main window to load prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the properties for the project choose your custom splash screen as splashscreen object for the project. This should automatically use your splash screen as the project's splash.

Comment: yes, I already have that setup. The Splash Screen is displayed in front of the Main Window, I want it displayed for 3 seconds **then** the Main Window displayed

Comment: You can add a forced delay by using a timer control on the splash screen, set an interval of 3000 and trigger the timer event to show the main form.